# SQL data fetch with order by where condition (first where/like result first in order second where/like result in next order))

Tags: sql, search, sql-order-by, search-engine

SQL data fetch with order by where condition (first where/like result first in order second, while second where/like result in next order and next where/like in next order)

actually i want to get result first from brand, second from title and third from cat1/2/3 for search "dev"

```
INSERT INTO product_list (product_id, brand, title, cat1, cat2, cat3) VALUES
(1, 'lux mos',      'lux mos',      'lux mos dev',  'lux mos', 'lux mos'),
(2, 'lux mos',      'lux mos dev',  'lux mos',      'lux mos', 'lux mos'),
(3, 'lux mos dev',  'lux mos',      'lux mos',      'lux mos', 'lux mos'),
(4, 'lux mos',      'lux mos',      'lux mos dev',  'lux mos', 'lux mos'),
(5, 'lux mos dev',  'lux mos',      'lux mos',      'lux mos', 'lux mos');
```

then result for search "dev" is as product_id in order 3, 2, 1, 4

`public function ProductList($PageNo = 0) {
    $search_str = 'dev';
    $this->db->select('*');
    if(isset($_GET['q'])){
        $this->db->or_like('Brand', $search_str);
        $this->db->or_like('title', $search_str);
        $string = str_replace(' ', '-', $search_str); // Replaces all spaces with hyphens.
        $string = preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z\-]/', '', $string);
        $string = strtolower($string);

        $str_Arr = explode(' ', $string);
        foreach($str_Arr as $str){
            if($str!=''){
                $this->db->or_like('Brand', $str);
                $this->db->or_like('title', $str);
            }
        }
    }
    elseif(isset($_GET['cat1'])){
        $this->db->where('cat1',$_GET['cat1']);
    }
    elseif(isset($_GET['cat2'])){
        $this->db->where('cat2',$_GET['cat2']);
    }
    elseif(isset($_GET['cat3'])){
        $this->db->where('cat3 like','%'.$_GET['cat3'].'%');
    }

    $this->db->group_by("product_id");
    $query = $this->db->get('product_list', 8, $PageNo*8);
    $result = $query->result();

    return $result;`

}